# jQuery get fields for form submission

Tags: jquery, forms, serialization, submit

HTML markup generated is below

#### HTML

```
<input type="hidden" name="CONTROL$POSITION" value="" id="control_position_1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="CONTROL$POSITION" value="" id="control_position_2"/>
<input type="hidden" name="CONTROL$POSITION" value="" id="control_position_3"/>
```

Where each hidden field value represents the draggable controls x and y co-ordinates. I would like to get the output like below on a button click. I am confused as to what needs to be done

#### Output

`name$xvalue$yvalue[seperator]repeats`

here is a simple iteration

`name=position,x=10,y=10,seperator=§` so this would be output `position$10$10§`.

#### Question:

How to generate a output on button click as given in output section above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not completely understanding all the details, but the general solution could look like:

```
var res = [];
$('input[name="CONTROL$POSITION"]').each(function () {
    res.push('name=position,' + $(this).val());
})
alert(res.join('§'));
```

Comment: you can't append to an array you can only push

Comment: Correct. That's a side effect of using both Python and JS :)